# ZendFramework 2.3 - Set module wise error layouts

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I am new with Zend 2.3 and creating a web application. In this web application, I have two different modules and they have two different layout structures.

I have already set different layouts for both modules which only works when there is no any error in dispatch. Now I want to set different layouts for 404 error pages.

Below is both modules onBootstrap() ::

Module A Module.php

```
public function onBootstrap($e) {
        $eventManager   = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();

        $serviceManager = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager();
        $eventManager->attach(MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH_ERROR, function($event) use ($serviceManager ) {
            $response = $event->getResponse();
            if ($response->getStatusCode() == "404")
            {
                $controller = $event->getTarget();
                $controllerClass = get_class($controller);
                $config = $event->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('config');
                $controller->layout('radmin/error');
            }
        }, -100);

        $eventManager->getSharedManager()
            ->attach('Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractController', 'dispatch', function($e) {
                $controller = $e->getTarget();
                $controllerClass = get_class($controller);
                $moduleNamespace = substr($controllerClass, 0, strpos($controllerClass, '\\'));
                $config = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('config');
                if (isset($config['module_layouts'][$moduleNamespace])) {
                    $controller->layout($config['module_layouts'][$moduleNamespace]);
                }
            }, 100);
    }
```

Module A module.config.php

```
'view_manager' => array(
        'display_not_found_reason' => true,
        'display_exceptions'       => true,
        'doctype'                  => 'HTML5',
        'not_found_template'       => 'error/404',
        'exception_template'       => 'error/index',
        'template_map' => array(
            'radmin/layout'           => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/radmin.phtml',
            'error/404'               => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/404.phtml',
            'radmin/error'             => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/index.phtml',
            'javascripts'             => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/javascripts.phtml',
        ),
        'template_path_stack' => array(
           'radmin' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
        ),
    ),
    'module_layouts' => array(
        'Radmin' => 'layout/radmin.phtml'
),
```

Same way for another module Module B. But its not working. For each module it takes Application layout for error page.

I am getting :: Fatal error: Call to undefined method Zend\Mvc\Application::layout()

Please kindly help me in this problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the **view_manager->template_path_stack->modulea** do not match up with **view_manager->module_layouts->Radmin**. What is your actual module name in the source. Is it Modulea.php or Radmin.php? It should look like this if the module name was supposedly Blah.php view_manager->template_path_stack->blah and view_manager->module_layouts->Blah.

Give that a try and see if it works.

Comment: Sorry that is my mistake in copy paste of code. Updated code now.

Comment: My target is to set two different layout for error pages of two different  modules. i.e set module wise error page layout.

Answer (score 0):

The layout template for exceptions and 404 errors is not resolved from the controller class. So setting the layout for errors on the controller like you do doesn't help:

```
$controller->layout('radmin/error');
```

---

### For 404 errors

Instead the layout for 404 errors is collected from the `not_found_template` value in the config and injected in the `RouteNotFoundStrategy` when it is created by the `HttpRouteNotFoundStrategyFactory`. You can see that [here on line 84 in the factory](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-mvc/blob/master/src/Service/HttpRouteNotFoundStrategyFactory.php#L84).

You might be able to overwrite the value by collecting the `RouteNotFoundStrategy` instance yourself from the service manager:

```
$routeNotFoundStrategy = $serviceManager->get('HttpRouteNotFoundStrategy');
$routeNotFoundStrategy->setNotFoundTemplate('radmin/404');
```

---

### For exceptions

Similarly the layout for exceptions/errors is collected from the `exception_template` value in the config and injected in the `ExceptionStrategy` when it is created by the `HttpExceptionStrategyFactory`. You can see that [here on line 71 in the factory](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-mvc/blob/master/src/Service/HttpExceptionStrategyFactory.php#L71).

You might be able to overwrite the value by collecting the `HttpExceptionStrategy` instance yourself from the service manager:

```
$exceptionStrategy = $serviceManager->get('HttpExceptionStrategy');
$exceptionStrategy->setExceptionTemplate('radmin/error');
```

This is not tested, but I am almost sure it should work...

---

**Note:** *I am not sure whether this is considered good practice though. You could also consider sticking to the default layouts for 404 errors and exceptions and simply add some custom code inside the layout itself. That might be simpler and will probably have lead to less overhead.*